# how to call second Stage from main stage in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am JavaFX beginner and I am struck at this thing.I made following-

I have a main stage which has button

```
btnShow.setOnAction(e->{

        String finalList="";
        for (int sub=0;sub<finalArrayList.size();sub++){
            Worker worker=finalArrayList.get(sub);
            finalList+=worker.getName()+"\t";
            finalList+=worker.getCity()+"\n";
        }
        StageTwo(finalList); 

    });
```

and the Following is another stage I want to call from main stage

```
public class StageTwo extends Stage {

    private TextArea txtDisp=new TextArea();
    private StackPane stack=new StackPane(txtDisp); 
    private Scene scene= new Scene(stack,700,300);

    public StageTwo(String finalList){

        txtDisp.setText(finalList);
        setTitle("Display Workers"); 
        setScene(scene); 
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "calling the stage" but invoking constructors requires the use of the `new` keyword and a stage is not shown automatically. BTW: consider using `StringBuilder` for the string concatenation in the loop since it does not create a new string for every part that is added.

Comment: @fabian how to do that..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a new stage from a different stage just instantiate the stage object and then call the `show()` method.

So this code:

```
  btnShow.setOnAction(e->{

    String finalList="";
    for (int sub=0;sub<finalArrayList.size();sub++){
        Worker worker=finalArrayList.get(sub);
        finalList+=worker.getName()+"\t";
        finalList+=worker.getCity()+"\n";
    }
    StageTwo(finalList); 

});
```

Should be changed to this code:

```
  btnShow.setOnAction(e->{

    String finalList="";
    for (int sub=0;sub<finalArrayList.size();sub++){
        Worker worker=finalArrayList.get(sub);
        finalList+=worker.getName()+"\t";
        finalList+=worker.getCity()+"\n";
    }
   //create a new instance and call the show method
   new StageTwo(finalList).show(); 

});
```

Now when the button is clicked StageTwo will be shown.

If you would like to read up more to understand how stages work I would reccomend this article https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html.